# how to connect mongo read replica from python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I can connect with my mongo access with read preference on replica by following command:

```
mongo DBHOST:27017/db
db.auth('username','password')
rs.slaveOk()
```

I tried with python, but didnt worked.

Python

```
from pymongo import Connection  
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('mongodb://username:password@DBHOST:27017/DB',readPreference='secondaryPreferred')
```

Any help?

Comment: What's the error? And btw talking about "Read replica" in MongoDB is wrong, you probably have a "Replica set".

Comment: need more info about your queston. but from the doc, it said "client = MongoClient('localhost:27017', replicaSet='foo', readPreference='secondaryPreferred')" maybe you need to set the replicaSet name?